# Why does VS claim that my project is of DLL type when it is set as an EXE type?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to launch the Console.Tests part of  https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis in **Debug** mode (by pressing **F5**), so that I can place a breakpoint in it.

Visual Studio (2013), however, refuses to do so, claiming that my project is of DLL type:

[image]

**Why? What am I missing?**

BTW, building this project produces `Console.Tests.exe` in `Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ServiceStack.Redis-master\tests\Console.Tests\bin\Debug` which runs just fine.

Also, if I attempt to debug the project by right-clicking its menu, it also starts just fine:

[image]

**Why? What am I missing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Visual Studio which **StartUp project** it should run by right clicking on `Console.Tests` project in solution explorer and selecting **Set as Startup Project**.

Comment: Bingo. Accepting +1. Thank you!